# Android: How to open Facebook application on a post that I have its id

Tags: android, facebook

I want to open Facebook application - if installed - on a post on my wall (I have the post id), how can accomplish this? I tried the code below but it's not working, it causes an exception and it just opens Facebook application as in this picture.

[image]

```
public static Intent getOpenFacebookIntent(String aPostID) {

    try {
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/" + aPostID));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/" + aPostID));
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:**

This is a graph response when I use video.watches and it returns me a different post ID (Which is not working with fb:// scheme) than the one I find when I hover over the post time on my wall using PC browser (Which is working with fb:// scheme) .... How to get the right post id?

[image]

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
fb://page/
```

you will need to access

```
fb://post/{postId}?owner={uid}
```

where `postId` is in the `uid_postid` format.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you, what is the format of the uid_postid? Is this technique is official way provided by Facebook?

Comment: Could you please check my question here related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286234/android-how-to-get-the-correct-facebook-post-id-via-graph-api-to-use-it-with-fb

Comment: its what you get as ID for every post. The number before the underscore is basically the uid of the page or the user, which posted the post. And the number after the underscore is the postId. Yes, it's provided by facebook.

Comment: Thank you jogli5er for your help, but as in the link I provided in the comment above the post id provided by Facebook API doesn't open the Facebook application on the post and shows broken link, can you help?

Comment: The problem of your way opening the post: Have you looked at the id you get from your Request? Normally it is already in the 'uid_postid' format. And you should place the '?owner=uid' afterwards. It did not work, when I tried it out without it.

Comment: What Graph API request returns posts ids in 'uid_postid' format? because I tried /me/statuses and it returns the posts ids in postID format.

Comment: Post an example of the id you receive.

Comment: 10206193113855579 this is the format of the post ID I receive when I use (for example) video.watches, knowing that the post ID when you hover over the post time (via browser) is 10206193113815578 ... and that's why the first one is not working with fb:// scheme, but the second one (if I put it in my application statically) works with fb:// scheme. And this is the same format when I request /statuses, the only difference is when I use /statuses I get a post id identical to the one I get when I hover with the mouse over the post time (unlike /video.watches that returns me different post id).

Comment: so you need the id of your account, when you make your calls on /me. Then you put yourId_postId.

Comment: That's what I hoped for based on your answer above, I (temporarily) used my account id combined with post id provided by video.watches but it didn't work, but when I combined my account id with post id (via browser) it worked ... the problem is in the post id returned by graph api.

Comment: myID_PostID (via video.watches) doesn't work with fb:// scheme .... myID_PostID (Manually fetched from PC Browser) works with fb://scheme

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70238/discussion-between-jogli5er-and-astrount).

Comment: Hi, been a long time, how to pass a post id (in uid_postid) as a graph path in Android, I have it works on Graph API Explorer where uid_postid like (1234_4321) format, but using the same in Android throws error "unknown path component"